# Magento Payment method is should be enable but its not display in Frontend(checkout page)?

Tags: php, magento

Enable the Purchase order Payment Method in Magento admin but i don't want to  display in Front end Checkout page..
Any Solution plzzz...

Thanks,
Ram Sampathi

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the module output so that they will not show their result on frontend.It can be done 
System->configuration->advance.

Comment: I don't want only Purchase Order Payment method but i need remaining payment methods..

Comment: Go to System->configuration->payment options and then select Purchase Order Payment  and disable it from their.

Comment: I am not understanding your language.

Comment: purchase order payment method must be enable in back end.but this payment method title is not showing on front end....

Answer (score 0):

Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods

extend this block class.

Add a function getMethod()  this method to call parent getMethod.
Here in loop filter out Method in area is frontend.

Else there are Payment filter extensions that you should use.